# Images in CSV file don't show up in Anki

Tags: csv, anki

I'm trying to import a CSV set of notes that include image references into Anki.

I have a file with Cloze substitutions and in one note I am using an image in the text:

```
 <img src=”duck.jpg”> This picture is of a {{c1::duck}}
```

I've put duck.jpg in the media.collection folder (along side a lot of working media), but when I import it I see a broken image icon inside Anki.

Comment: It turns out OpenOffice was being "helpful" (or should that be “helpful”) by turning my quotation marks in the img tag into curly quotes (”) instead of normal quotes ("), which caused the img tag to be broken.

I went through the file and replaced with single quotes, which OpenOffice didn't mess with, and the tag now works fine and the images show up properly in Anki now.

Comment: If you have solved your question, please add the solution as an answer and accept your own answer so other users can easily see this question has been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out OpenOffice was being "helpful" (or should that be “helpful”) by turning my quotation marks in the img tag into curly quotes (”) instead of normal quotes ("), which caused the img tag to be broken. I went through the file and replaced with single quotes, which OpenOffice didn't mess with, and the tag now works fine and the images show up properly in Anki now.